# How to disable resize(maximize/minimize) button on Xamarin Forms (UWP)?

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, resize, disable

[image: Xamarin.Forms UWP]

Is there any way to disable the resize button on Xamarin Forms (UWP) ? Like the image with red square highlighted in the image above.

Comment: those 3 buttons are not controlled by uwp apis they are part of the OS itself so NO u cannot disable them, although u can change their background color.

Comment: i see, too bad then,  cannot control if user resize the the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Titlebar buttons are something that is controlled by the Windows itself, so you cannot remove it but you have limited control on it, like changing the background color. Further you can make your app to go fullscreen which will make the title bar disappear or you can extend your App in the title bar itself as mentioned in [this](https://dailydotnettips.com/how-to-place-custom-xaml-content-in-the-windows-universal-apps-title-bar/) blog post.

Comment: I see, by the way thanks for the other control of the title bar we can do.